# 1000 mp3 songs make HTML5 audio tag lag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have a personal website:
http://antonfrolov.net/music.html

I need an mp3 player over there.
I've got over 1 thousand mp3 tracks.

The thing is I have tried awesome Flash-mp3 Player but it doesn't read Cyrillic names.
So I went to HTML5 < audio > tag but for some (obvious for you) reason it loads every single song even though the songs are not playing, and the tag doesn't have 'autoplay' attribute.

What would be the Easiest way to do this for 1000+ songs?
Look how fast the Flash is: http://antonfrolov.net/musicbackup.html

(ENG-named track #6 works flawlessly, while RU-named track #7 refuses to be read)

Thank you guys and SO community =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't load audio before "play" button click. Create audio object dynamically destroying previous one.

Remove all audio tags, and add rel attributes to play buttons with proper audio source, something like this (jQuery):

```
<span class="playb" rel="j/28 Days Later/28 Days Later - Ave Maria.mp3"></span>
...
...
...
<span class="playb" rel="..."></span>
...
<script>
$('.playb').click(function(){
   $('audio').remove();
   $('<audio controls class><source src="'+$(this).attr('rel')+'" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>').appendTo($(this).parent());
});
</script>
```

PS. Someone may say that it is not the best practice to merge strings like this, and you should create `source` element first then set its `src` attribute and wrap with `audio` tag. But this one is simply faster, as jQuery doesn`t have to analize given code 1000 times.

Comment: JESUS! man that was awesome. I can tell how noobish I appear for not knowing basics of JS. Thank you a lot!

I feel shame. Still thanks a lot for this. Have a good day!